# using browser back arrow is launching previous modal or alert box … js issue - how do we prevent old modal and green notification from appearing again

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Happy Wednesday Experts!

I have a website, where there is an alert  which has code as below

```
 @if (\Session::get('message')<>'')
    <script>
        window.onload = function ()
        {
          message = 'Success message';
          $.notify(message, {timeout: 3000,pos: 'top-right'});
        }
    </script>
    @endif
```

Now, It is working perfectly. 
After I submit, I get a message from code behind "Success message" and now I moved to a different page. It is loaded without any problem. I decided to click on back button of browser and I see that success message. It shows the Alert message (success message) .

Could someone help me with this?

After show message, before moving any other page, I already cleared session message.

I believe I have something to do with caching and postbacks but not sure how or what to do

Comment: it's not that clear what you are asking or what you are expecting

Comment: @Edwin using browser back arrow is launching previous modal or alert box … js issue - how do we prevent old modal and green notification from appearing again

Comment: @Edwin Is this clear now ??

Comment: but if you reload the page shouldn't then do the same thing again? because you don't have any state that changed so your message will be shown again. I think you want something like one time message, is that right?

Comment: The answer is most likely that the previous page is cached, yes. But echoing scripts based on server state is a bad idea for that precise reason; I'd use an AJAX call to get the session state and display the message accordingly; that way the client will always properly reflect the server state, regardless of caching.

Comment: @ChrisG  previous page is cached, how to handle it ??

Comment: @AshishChaturvedi I already told you about the fix I'd try right there in my previous comment.

Comment: my friend i think you want the popup on click of button, you want to see that last popup again that was on page load with Alert message(success message).

Comment: @VirendraYaduvanshi sorry to say, but you should read the question again.